# How to fix this package installation error?

Tags: linux, installation, python, apt

When I tried to install python-pip on my Ubuntu on 04/18, I got this error. 
What should I do?

```
root@sklypc:/home/skly# apt install python-pip
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Некоторые пакеты не могут быть установлены. Возможно, то, что вы просите,
неосуществимо, или же вы используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где
запрошенные вами пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация, возможно, вам поможет:

Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 python-pip : Зависит: python:any (< 2.8)
              Зависит: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
              Рекомендует: build-essential но он не будет установлен
              Рекомендует: python-all-dev (>= 2.6) но он не будет установлен
              Рекомендует: python-setuptools но он не будет установлен
              Рекомендует: python-wheel но он не будет установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки: у вас зафиксированы сломанные пакеты.
```

Translated by Google

```
root@sklypc:/home/skly# apt install python-pip
Reading package lists ... Done
Building a dependency tree
Reading status information ... Done
Some packages cannot be installed. Perhaps what you are asking is
impracticable, or you are using an unstable version of the distribution, where
The packages you requested have not yet been created or have been removed from Incoming.
The following information may help you:

The following packages have unsatisfied dependencies:
 python-pip : Depends: python: any (<2.8)
              Depends: python: any (> = 2.7.5-5 ~)
              Recommended: build-essential but it will not be installed
              Recommended: python-all-dev (> = 2.6) but it will not be installed
              Recommended: python-setuptools but it will not be installed
              Recommended: python-wheel but it will not be installed
E: Unable to fix errors: you have broken packages.
```

Comment: this happens with almost every package that I want to install

Comment: Can you please translate into the English Language your Question Body? Mother _Russia_ has not been teaching us the Slavic Languages for quite some time.

Comment: See [Problem when installing pip for python 2.7.16 in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140471/problem-when-installing-pip-for-python-2-7-16-in-ubuntu-18-04).  I also edited question to add Google translate of error - please correct it if it is wrong in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in a terminal: **`sudo apt-get install --fix-missing`**

This will instruct the package manager to fix the issue by downloading the missing packages and automatically resolving their dependencies.

Comment: the problem is not solved, the same error appears

Comment: So you want to install python-pip. The issue is that there are dependencies that your system is having trouble installing. Okay. So you've tried "--fix-missing". Next, try and make a list of all the packages that are needed and install them on your own. So go to https://packages.ubuntu.com/ and download the .deb file for each package and install using sudo dpkg -i name-of-package.deb. If this fails a third option is to upgrade your system (the error msg already indicates that your system may be unstable) so that it fixes anything that is missing i.e., sudo do-release-upgrade.